# Is 'internallength' always useful in custom type definition in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, performance, datatypes, composite-types

In our database we use a custom type to store 3D locations:

```
CREATE TYPE float3d AS (
  x real,
  y real,
  z real);
```

In many examples I see `INTERNALLENGTH` used as a parameter with the definition of custom types. Also, the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtype.html) tells me that "[t]he default assumption is that it is variable-length", if this parameter is omitted. Is this also true for types like the one above where the size can be calculated (3*4 bytes + 4byte padding)? So should I add 16 as internal length to the definition?

Also, are there other parameters that could improve the performance of handling many (~10,000,000) entries using this type?

Comment: Your  biggest issues will be (a) alignment costs and (b) the relatively huge 24 byte per row overhead of Pg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `INTERNALLENGTH` is only applicable to the creation of a new **base type**, which is a rather specialized operation for advanced users. It would require to provide input and output function etc.

What you display is the creation of a new **composite type**, which is a more common operation. There is no parameter `INTERNALLENGTH` for that purpose. [Read the manual once more.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-createtype.html)

To optimize disk space and performance I would rather avoid using composite types due to big row overhead. Details depend on the details of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, this answers my question. What overhead can I expect when I use this location type? Due to padding I would expect 24 byte. I often run queries that find rows matching a certain bounding box (`WHERE l.x > 10000 AND l.x < 12000 AND l.y > 40 AND l.y < 120.4 ...`). I've got a B-Tree index on each location component.

Comment: @tomka: I suggest you ask a new question (or two, actually!). Comments are not the place. You can always add a link to this one for context to avoid redundant typing.