# Good layout of 3d point data for spatial queries in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, spatial, composite-types

Like shown in [another](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72754/is-internallength-always-useful-in-custom-type-definition-in-postgres) question, I deal with a lot (>10,000,000) entries of points in a 3D space. These points are defined like this:

```
CREATE TYPE float3d AS (
  x real,
  y real,
  z real);
```

If I am not mistaken 3*8 bytes + 8 bytes padding are needed (`MAXALIGN` is 8) to store one of these points. Is there a better way to store this kind of data? In the afore mentioned question it was stated that composite types involve quite some overhead.

I oftentimes do spatial queries like this:

```
  SELECT t1.id, t1.parent_id, (t1.location).x, (t1.location).y, (t1.location).z,
         t1.confidence, t1.radius, t1.skeleton_id, t1.user_id,
         t2.id, t2.parent_id, (t2.location).x, (t2.location).y, (t2.location).z,
         t2.confidence, t2.radius, t2.skeleton_id, t2.user_id
  FROM treenode t1
       INNER JOIN treenode t2 ON
         (   (t1.id = t2.parent_id OR t1.parent_id = t2.id)
          OR (t1.parent_id IS NULL AND t1.id = t2.id))
        WHERE (t1.LOCATION).z = 41000.0
          AND (t1.LOCATION).x > 2822.6
          AND (t1.LOCATION).x < 62680.2
          AND (t1.LOCATION).y > 33629.8
          AND (t1.LOCATION).y < 65458.6
          AND t1.project_id = 1 LIMIT 5000;
```

A query like this takes about 160 ms, but I wonder if this could be reduced.

This is the table layout the structure is used in:

```
    Column     |           Type           |                       Modifiers                    
---------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id            | bigint                   | not null default nextval('location_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id       | integer                  | not null
 creation_time | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 edition_time  | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 project_id    | integer                  | not null
 location      | float3d                  | not null
 editor_id     | integer                  |
 parent_id     | bigint                   |
 radius        | real                     | not null default 0
 confidence    | smallint                 | not null default 5
 skeleton_id   | integer                  | not null

Indexes:
    "treenode_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "treenode_parent_id" btree (parent_id)
    "treenode_project_id_location_x_index" btree (project_id, ((location).x))
    "treenode_project_id_location_y_index" btree (project_id, ((location).y))
    "treenode_project_id_location_z_index" btree (project_id, ((location).z))
    "treenode_project_id_skeleton_id_index" btree (project_id, skeleton_id)
    "treenode_project_id_user_id_index" btree (project_id, user_id)
    "treenode_skeleton_id_index" btree (skeleton_id)
```

Comment: have you considered PostGIS to manage spatial data ?

Comment: Check out my answer for a solution with PostGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composite type is clean design, but it does *not* help performance *at all*.

First of all, `float` translates to `float8` a.k.a. `double precision` in Postgres. You are building on a misunderstanding.
The [`real`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) data type occupies 4 byte (not 8). It has to be aligned at multiples of 4 bytes.

Measure actual sizes with [`pg_column_size()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE).

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6dc9a/3) demonstrating actual sizes.

The composite type `real3d` occupies 36 bytes. That's:

```
23 byte tuple header
1 byte padding
4 bytes real x
4 bytes real y
4 bytes real z
---
36 bytes
```

If you embed that into a table, padding *may* have to be added. On the other hand the header of the type can be 3 byte smaller on disk. Representation on disk is typically a bit smaller than in RAM. Doesn't make a lot of difference.

More:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)

#### Table layout

Use this equivalent design to reduce row size *substantially*:

```
    Column     |           Type           |                       Modifiers
---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------
 id            | bigint                   | not null default nextval(...
 creation_time | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 edition_time  | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 user_id       | integer                  | not null
 project_id    | integer                  | not null
 location_x    | real                     | not null
 location_y    | real                     | not null
 location_z    | real                     | not null
 radius        | real                     | not null default 0
 skeleton_id   | integer                  | not null
 confidence    | smallint                 | not null default 5
 parent_id     | bigint                   |
 editor_id     | integer                  |
```

Test before and after to verify my claim:

```
SELECT pg_relation_size('treenode') As table_size;

SELECT avg(pg_column_size(t) AS avg_row_size
FROM   treenode t;
```

More details:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation and the SQL Fiddle example. So it seems it would help performance if I transform the `real3d` type (as it should be called) into three columns on of the `treenode` table, correct?

Comment: @tomka: Absolutely. But there's more ... Consider the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I try to rebuild the table with your suggested layout. Is the order of the columns important for performance aside from alignment/passing issues?

Comment: @tomka: Yes. Well, it's mainly "column tetris" to reduce storage size, which helps overall performance. I optimized the order. Have a look at the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468). Plus, I took a couple of other considerations into account (NULL columns last helps *a tiny bit*. BTW, do you actually need a `bigint` pk? Do you expect *a lot* of rows over the course of time?

Comment: What were your considerations for reordering the columns aside from alignment? I could imagine that often read columns should come first? Unfortunately, I do need a `bigint` pk. I expect the table to grow to some billions of rows.

Comment: @tomka: Yes, frequently accessed columns first, but don't worry much about that, the effect is practically negligibly. `NULL` columns last, helps a bit more, still hardly relevant. Size matters. If you don't have *any* NULL values in any individual row, you also save 8 bytes for the *NULL bitmask*. [Details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229805/how-much-disk-space-is-needed-to-store-a-null-value-using-postgresql-db/7654497#7654497)

Answer (score 1):

## PostGIS

PostGIS is easy and gives you a [bunch of functions for you to query with.](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html) The PostGIS solution is simple and it'll use an index too. Here we use 3d (to accommodate your z), but I'm not sure if you need it.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;

CREATE TABLE t AS (
  geom  geometry(point)
);
INSERT INTO t(geom) VALUES (ST_MakePoint(x,y,z));

CREATE INDEX idx ON table USING gist(geom gist_geometry_ops_nd);

SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE geom &&& ST_3DMakeBox(
  ST_MakePoint(2822.6, 33629.8, 41000.0),
  ST_MakePoint(62680.2, 65458.6, 41000.0)
);
```

If all of your points and geoms have an z = 41000, just use 2d geoms.