# Is harmfulness of idle in transaction connections a myth?

Tags: postgresql

There are some sources on the internet which insist `idle in transaction` connections may prevent vacuum from cleaning up dead tuples, below are some examples:

[User Guide for Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/proactive-insights.idle-txn.html):

> A transaction in the idle in transaction state can hold locks that block other queries. **It can also prevent VACUUM (including autovacuum) from cleaning up dead rows, leading to index or table bloat or transaction ID wraparound**.

[Cybertec blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/idle_in_transaction_session_timeout-terminating-idle-transactions-in-postgresql/)

> A long transaction is actually not a problem – the problem starts if a long transaction and many small changes have to exist. **Remember: The long transaction can cause VACUUM to not clean out your dead rows**.

Actually, there are plenty of them, however from my perspective that sounds absolutely ridiculous: in the most cases transaction isolation level is read committed, that in turn means there is no need to keep dead tuples for such transactions, moreover, I have found [alternative opinion on that topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77587/271578):

> It is not really long-lived transactions, but **long lived *snapshots***. Certainly a long running select or insert statement will do that. **For isolation levels higher than read-committed, the whole transaction will retain the snapshot until it is down**, so if some opens a repeatable read transaction and then goes on vacation without committing it, that would be a problem. Hung-up prepared transactions will as well (if you don't know what a prepared transaction is, then you probably aren't using them).

or [Pavel Luzanov's comment under Cybertec blogpost](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/idle_in_transaction_session_timeout-terminating-idle-transactions-in-postgresql/#comment-3846188971):

> I believe that example of a long transaction is true only for Repeatable Read (or Serializable) isolation level. But by default BEGIN used Read Commited. So, after SELECT in the first session finished, VACUUM will remove dead rows in a table after subsequent UPDATE, DELETE commands in the session 2.

which is actually confirmed by @[Bill Karwin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2703/bill-karwin) in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/332404/271578) (thanks!)

The question is: are there "valid" "non-fictional" scenarios when `idle in transaction` connections should be considered harmful? (I'm not asking about transaction with isolation level higher than read committed, transaction or connection leaks, long transaction holding locks, etc).

Comment: If the READ COMMITTED transaction has done any DML or FOR UPDATE queries, then it will also prevent clean up until it is committed, and so will cause bloat.  Even if it has done nothing but pure SELECT, there may be some corner cases where it could cause bloat.  Tickling the dragon is a silly game to play.

Comment: @jjanes the "corner cases" is exactly what I have asked about, would you mind shedding some light on that?

Comment: I don't know what the corner cases might be, I just can't rule them out.  When I do a controlled experiment, maybe the experiment just doesn't happen to hit those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true that a transaction itself does not block the progress of `VACUUM`. A transaction only blocks `VACUUM` if one of these two conditions are satisfied:

1. The transaction has a transaction ID assigned (that is, it has modified something in that database).
2. The transaction holds a *snapshot* of the database. A snapshot is a data structure that determines which other transactions are visible to a certain transactions. Snapshots are held open

   - as long as an SQL statement is running (so a long running query can block `VACUUM` progress)
   - while there is a cursor open
   - on the `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, for the whole duration of the transaction

You can use the query from [my article on the topic](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/) to see if there is a transaction that blocks `VACUUM`'s progress:

```
SELECT pid, datname, usename, state, backend_xmin, backend_xid
FROM pg_stat_activity
      /* holds a snapshot */
WHERE backend_xmin IS NOT NULL
      /* has a transaction ID */
   OR backend_xid IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY greatest(age(backend_xmin), age(backend_xid)) DESC;
```

Comment: Did I understand property (based on your [SO A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63840171/3426309)) non null `backend_xmin` means `tx` has established a snapshot (via query/cursor or setting isolation level higher than `RC`) and non null `backend_xid` means `tx` has modified something or acquired a lock via `select ... for ...`?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, read-committed transactions do not block vacuum.

Demo:

I created a table with 2<sup>20</sup> rows. We can see that it has that many live tuples, and 0 dead tuples.

```
postgres=# select n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, relname from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='mytable';
 n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | relname 
------------+------------+---------
    1048576 |          0 | mytable
```

Then I query it in a transaction, but do not commit yet. This establishes a snapshot.

```
postgres=# start transaction;
START TRANSACTION
postgres=*# select count(*) from mytable;
  count  
---------
 1048576
(1 row)
```

In a second window, I delete half of the rows.

```
postgres=# delete from mytable where id % 2 = 0;
DELETE 524288
```

Because my first window's transaction is read-committed by default, it updates its snapshot to see the results of the deletions.

```
postgres=*# select count(*) from mytable;
 count  
--------
 524288
(1 row)
```

I still have not committed that transaction.

If I measure the dead tuples very promptly, I see they are still hanging around in the table.

```
postgres=# select n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, relname from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='mytable';
 n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | relname 
------------+------------+---------
     524288 |     524288 | mytable
```

All I have to do is wait for `autovacuum_naptime` for autovacuum to run. This is 1 minute by default.

```
postgres=# select n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, relname from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='mytable';
 n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | relname 
------------+------------+---------
     524288 |          0 | mytable
```