# Postgres partial index on IS NULL not working

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

#### Postgres version

Using PostgreSQL 10.3.

#### Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
  id bigserial primary key,
  state character varying,
  closed timestamp
);

CREATE INDEX  "state_index" ON "tickets" ("state")
  WHERE ((state)::text = 'open'::text));
```

#### Cardinality

The table contains 1027616 rows, with 51533 of the rows having `state = 'open'` and `closed IS NULL`, or 5%.

A query with a condition on `state` performs well using an index scan as expected:

```
explain analyze select * from tickets where state = 'open';

Index Scan using state_index on tickets  (cost=0.29..16093.57 rows=36599 width=212) (actual time=0.025..22.875 rows=37346 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.212 ms
Execution time: 25.697 ms
```

I am trying to achieve the same or better performance for the query with the condition `closed IS NULL` so that I can drop the `state` column and rely on the `closed` column for fetching the same rows. `closed` is `null` for the same rows where `state = 'open'`, hence the `state` column is redundant.

```
select * from tickets where closed IS NULL;
```

However, none of the indexes I've tried result in a single index scan like the first query. Below are the indexes I've tried along with the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results.

A partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX  "closed_index" ON "tickets"  ("closed") WHERE (closed IS NULL)

explain analyze select * from tickets where closed IS NULL;

Bitmap Heap Scan on tickets  (cost=604.22..38697.91 rows=36559 width=212) (actual time=12.879..48.780 rows=37348 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (closed IS NULL)
  Heap Blocks: exact=14757
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on closed_index  (cost=0.00..595.09 rows=36559 width=0) (actual time=7.585..7.585 rows=37348 loops=1)
Planning time: 4.831 ms
Execution time: 52.068 ms
```

An expression index:

```
CREATE INDEX  "closed_index" ON "tickets" ((closed IS NULL))

explain analyze select * from tickets where closed IS NULL;

Seq Scan on tickets  (cost=0.00..45228.26 rows=36559 width=212) (actual time=0.025..271.418 rows=37348 loops=1)
  Filter: (closed IS NULL)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 836578
Planning time: 7.992 ms
Execution time: 274.504 ms
```

A partial expression index:

```
CREATE INDEX  "closed_index" ON "tickets" ((closed IS NULL))
  WHERE (closed IS NULL);

explain analyze select * from tickets where closed IS NULL;

Bitmap Heap Scan on tickets  (cost=604.22..38697.91 rows=36559 width=212) (actual time=177.109..238.008 rows=37348 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (closed IS NULL)
  Heap Blocks: exact=14757
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "closed_index"  (cost=0.00..595.09 rows=36559 width=0) (actual time=174.598..174.598 rows=37348 loops=1)
Planning time: 23.063 ms
Execution time: 241.292 ms
```

## UPDATED

#### Expanded table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
  id bigserial primary key,
  state character varying,
  closed timestamp,
  created timestamp,
  updated timestamp,
  title character varying,
  size integer NOT NULL,
  comment_count integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX  "state_index" ON "tickets" ("state")
  WHERE ((state)::text = 'open'::text));
```

#### Cardinality:

The table contains 1027616 rows, with 51533 of the rows having state = 'open' and closed IS NULL, or 5%. As mentioned above, I am trying to drop the `state` column so I want to be able to fetch the same rows using a condition on the `closed` column instead.

Query with condition on `state` column uses index scan.

```
explain analyze select id, title, created, closed, updated from tickets where state = 'open';

Index Scan using state_index on tickets  (cost=0.29..22901.58 rows=49356 width=72) (actual time=0.107..49.599 rows=51533 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.511 ms
Execution time: 54.366 ms
```

I'd like the same performance (index scan, ideally) when switching to querying on the `closed` column. I tried the partial index on `id` and `closed IS NULL`:

```
CREATE INDEX closed_index ON tickets (id) WHERE closed IS NULL;

VACUUM ANALYZE tickets;

explain analyze select id, title, created, closed, updated from tickets where closed IS NULL;

Bitmap Heap Scan on tickets  (cost=811.96..33999.42 rows=49461 width=72) (actual time=7.868..47.080 rows=51537 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (closed IS NULL)
  Heap Blocks: exact=17479
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on closed_index  (cost=0.00..799.60 rows=49461 width=0) (actual time=4.868..4.868 rows=51537 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.222 ms
Execution time: 51.028 ms
```

Comment: I've referenced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966218/postgresql-create-an-index-to-quickly-distinguish-null-from-non-null-values

Comment: Ignoring your question, if you look for a better index for your use case it would be probably best to have a single character not null state column, more compact, quick to compare, can transport mor states than closed is null and you could avoid Nullable completely.

Comment: @eckes I've considered that, but I do not have more states than closed. @eckes Are there any other advantages to using an additional single char or boolean not null column? The advantages have to outweigh the cost of having an additional, slightly redundant column since the `closed` column is necessary.

Comment: Well, hard to say if you change the question, the index on a fixed char (partial or not) will be much smaller. Of course it only makes sense if you can omit the current state column and the index on closed column.

Comment: Removing the `state` column, as its only *state* is represented in `closed IS NULL / NOT NULL`, is the *optimal* solution. One more detail: the 2nd query of your addition is actually *faster* (51 ms >> 54 ms). So the problem to address does not seem to be there to begin with. Still wondering where that index scan came from. And why the 2nd query has `rows=51537` while the 1st has `rows=51533`. More inconsistencies?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Not sure about the `51537` vs `51533` rows, I might've been doing some writes to the table in the midst of testing. Just to confirm what you said and to clarify for @eckes, I am trying to remove the `state` column and ONLY rely on the `closed` column. @ErwinBrandstetter the 2nd query isn't actually faster, is just happened to be when I ran it that time. In informal benchmarks the 2nd query is marginally slower.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the central piece of information:

> with ~15% of the rows having `state = 'open'` and `closed IS NULL`

is supposed to mean the same 15 % of all 1031584 rows meet both these conditions <sub>(all details matter!)</sub>. Both conditions should perform equally - returning around *155k* rows (!)

Your query plans show *37346* qualifying rows, ~ 3.6 % not 15 %. Something's still not right in your question.

With 3.6 %, indexes only start to make sense. Your tiny row size effectively occupies ~ 52 bytes per row, around 155 rows per page. That would be 5-6 hits per page for a completely random distribution. Postgres has to read *all* pages anyway and a ***sequential scan*** should be the fastest plan. Filtering the misses should be faster than involving indexes in any way.

Typically, qualifying rows are more or less clustered and the fewer data pages are involved the more sense it would make to involve an index. All **bitmap index scans**, though, I see hardly any case for an *index scan*. Even far less (as far as there can be much "less" than "hardly any") for the 15 % you claim.

For your *updated* numbers (~ 5% of all rows match) I would still rather expect bitmap index scans than index scans. A possible explanation: **table bloat** with lots of dead tuples. You mentioned a high write load. That would result in fewer and fewer live tuples per data page and favor index scans (as compared to bitmap index scans). You might re-test your initial query after a `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` (if you can afford an exclusive lock on the table!). If my hypothesis holds, the physical table size would shrink substantially and you would then see a bitmap index scan instead of the index scan (and faster, too).

- [For alignment optimized table is bigger than original table - why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72875/for-alignment-optimized-table-is-bigger-than-original-table-why/72878#72878)
- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)

You may need more aggressive `autovacuum` settings. See:

- [Aggressive Autovacuum on PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/aggressive-autovacuum-on-postgresql/21649#21649)

#### Partial index

Your "expression index" and "partial expression index" are not useful. We don't need `closed IS NULL` as actual index expression (which is always `true` here).  The expression only adds cost and no gain.

The first, plain partial index is the more useful variant. But don't use `closed` as index expression (again, always `NULL` here). Instead, use any column possibly useful to other queries, and ideally never updated to avoid additional cost and index bloat. The primary key column `id` is the natural candidate in absence of other useful applications:

```
CREATE INDEX closed_index ON tickets (id) WHERE closed IS NULL;
```

**Or**, if `id` is not useful, consider a *constant* instead:

```
CREATE INDEX closed_index ON tickets ((1)) WHERE closed IS NULL;
```

This makes the actual index column useless like in other dismissed variants - but it avoids all additional costs and dependencies. Related:

- [Get count estimates from pg_class.reltuples for given conditions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115873/get-count-estimates-from-pg-class-reltuples-for-given-conditions/115918#115918)

#### What I *might* try:

Only makes sense if you don't have many other writes on the the rows in question (The added columns `updated` and `comments_count` make me doubt it.)

*Create a partial index with `id` and the other relevant columns (*few & small*) as index expressions, and capitalize on it with a suitable query to get index-only scans:*

```
CREATE INDEX closed_index ON tickets (id, title, created, updated)
WHERE closed IS NULL;

VACUUM ANALYZE tickets;   -- just to prove idx-only is possible

SELECT id, title, created, updated
     , NULL::timestamp AS closed  -- redundant, rather drop it
FROM   tickets
WHERE  closed IS NULL;
```

We don't need `SELECT *`, `closed IS NULL` is given by the `WHERE` clause. So we can use the tiny partial index in a fast **index-only scan** - assuming you meet the preconditions (that's why I threw in `VACUUM` to update the visibility map up there). This is the rare case where queries reading more than ~ 5 % of all rows still happily use the index (even up to including the whole table).

There seems to be redundancy in your design, simplifications should be possible.

This works since Postgres 9.6, [quoting the release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/release-9-6.html#AEN133534)

> - Allow use of an [**index-only scan**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) on a partial index when the index's `WHERE` clause references columns that are not indexed (Tomas
>   Vondra, Kyotaro Horiguchi)
>
> For example, an index defined by `CREATE INDEX tidx_partial ON t(b) WHERE a > 0` can now be used for an index-only scan by a query that
> specifies `WHERE a > 0` and does not otherwise use `a`. Previously
> this was disallowed because a is not listed as an index column.

Or the information in your question is misleading.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL partial index unused when created on a table with existing data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99323/postgresql-partial-index-unused-when-created-on-a-table-with-existing-data/99324#99324)
- [Unexpected Seq Scan when doing query against boolean with value NULL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27681/unexpected-seq-scan-when-doing-query-against-boolean-with-value-null/27693#27693)
- [Postgres not using index when index scan is much better option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34584053/939860)

If you don't see index-only scans with this, even immediately after running `VACUUM`, then high write load may be in the way and the visibility map just never reaches a state that would allow index-only scans. [The manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-VISIBILITY-MAP) Or you have another problem in your DB keeping `VACUUM` from doing its job. Related:

- [Postgres: “vacuum” command does not clean up dead tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47921342/939860)

Comment: I don't understand is why `state_index` results in an Index Scan whereas `closed_index` results in a Bitmap Heap Scan -> Bitmap Index Scan. That is, the same number of rows are involved so shouldn't the query on `closed` also use an index scan versus a bitmap index scan?

Comment: Good question. But the more immediate question: Even with just 5% of qualifying rows and a bit wider rows (according to your Q update) we should not see an index scan *at all*. Bitmap index scan or index-only scan. (Try the updated solution for index-only scans.)

Comment: I *do* a fair amount of writes to the table so I don't think your updated solution makes sense. But I'm still not understanding why your first solution did not result in an index scan with `closed` like the one on `state` since the same rows are at play. For example, the index `CREATE INDEX closed_index ON tickets (closed) WHERE closed IS NULL;` seems like it's the exact same thing as `CREATE INDEX  "state_index" ON "tickets" ("state") WHERE ((state)::text = 'open'::text));` in terms of resulting in an index scan with my example queries, no?

Comment: @GeekJock: Really not sure why you got that index scan. And I am flat out surprised that it should be the fastest plan for the given numbers. I'd expected a bitmap index scan to be faster. But there are so many factors for performance that I could not be *certain* until tested. Be that as it may, I added more on the simple partial index. Consider the variant with the constant expression. Might be cheaper overall. (But the `SELECT` query should be just as fast.)

Comment: Ok, I just tried your latest example and it DID generate an index scan. So it IS possible :)

Comment: So whereas I am confused as to why the first `closed` index was NOT generating an index scan, you are confused why the original `state` index WAS producing an index scan? And your logic for this is at the beginning of your answer, just to confirm?

Comment: Yes, like you, I'd expect the same query plan. But I'd expect a bitmap index scan for both. Maybe you have a fast storage system and very low cost for index tuples and random page cost - and matching settings for `cpu_index_tuple_cost` etc. Or, more likely, **table bloat** with lots of dead tuples. (You mentioned a high write load.) That would make index scans more attractive, comparatively. I strongly suggest to look into this. You may need more aggressive vacuum settings. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21649/3684