# Are unique indexes used to verifiy unicity on insert?

Tags: postgresql, index

**PostgreSQL 13.5, PostGIS 3.2, Windows server 2012**

Here is the table I have created

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activite.unobs_rest
(
gid integer NOT NULL,
numunobs character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
typunobs character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
interpret character varying(60) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
datedebut bigint,
datefin integer,
gidoperef integer NOT NULL,
geom geometry(Geometry,2154),
periode character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
CONSTRAINT pk_gid PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
```

The table contains **412859 rows**.
Here are the partial indexes :

```
create unique index idx_2col_geom_numunobs on unobs_rest (MD5(st_asbinary(geom)), numunobs) where numunobs is not null;
create unique index idx_1col_geom on unobs_rest (MD5(st_asbinary(geom))) where numunobs is null;
```

Indexes are supposed to prevent duplicates when inserting a row with the same `geom&numunobs` or the same `geom&numunobs IS NULL` of an existing row.

But this doesn't work.

After reading [Postgres partial index on IS NULL not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229924/postgres-partial-index-on-is-null-not-working), I have updated the statistics, even if I don't run select query :

```
analyze activite.unobs_rest (geom)
analyze activite.unobs_rest (numunobs)
```

But again, I can copy and paste an existing row without any problem, which I don't want.

**question** Is there a way to know if indexes are used when I try to insert a row in `unobs_rest` ?

Comment: Please show us how you "*copy and paste*" existing rows.

Comment: I am using QGis 3.16 in edition session : select a polygon, copy and paste. But I just realized that  I have **the** expected error when I try to insert two times the same polygon with a transaction in pgAdmin4 : `begin; insert into...SELECT...ST_geomFromText(...)`. Well...new challenge I guess : why this QGIS behavior ?

Comment: QGIS cannot insert anything in the database that the database doesn't allow. So either the row is not inserted, or the values differ (however slightly).

Comment: Exactly, the point is when using QGIS on `unobs_rest`, the geometrytype is `multisurface`. But all the polygons in `unobs_rest` are `multipolygon` ! So no duplicates for PostGres when I save. I have to find a way to get rid of `multisurface` in this case.

Comment: @Leehan  If you are inserting multisurfaces, how can the table not be having multisurfaces in it?  If you have a before trigger that converts multisurfaces to multipolygons, then the constraint will be applied after the conversion.

Comment: @jjanes of course. But I discovered that QGIS was inserting multisurfaces - instead of mulitpolygons like I was thinking - today ! And yes I will create a trigger to convert multisurfaces.