# Index on expression (regular expression pattern matching) is not used in query

Tags: postgresql, index, regex

In my **PostgreSQL 12.8** database, I have a relatively simple table `the_table` with a column `value` with type `varchar`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.the_table (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    label character varying,
    value character varying,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
);
```

I would like to query for all rows with a value that is formatted as an email address.
The query looks like this: `SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE value ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9.$%&*+/=?^_{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'`.

As there are a several million rows in that table, I try to speed up this query by adding a matching **expression index** with `CREATE INDEX index_the_table_on_email_values ON the_table ((value ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9.$%&*+/=?^_{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'));`

Unfortunately, the query planner does not utilize the index and performs a full scan on the table instead, which is very slow.

Can anybody help me fixing the index or tell me what other options I have?
I already considered a **generated** boolean column `is_email` instead. I could add an index to that generated column and query it directly. But this seems like a weird workaround for the original problem, which should be solvable with a matching index, correct?

Comment: "A lot of rows" is not a useful indication of quantity. And please always disclose your version of Postgres. And the (relevant part of) the table definition as `CREATE TABLE` script.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I updated the details accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me.  Did you ANALYZE the table after creating the index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be fair, your index on a `boolean` expression basically works, too.

The point is this: if there is a large percentage of "email" rows, no index is going to help (much) - except for special cases. Postgres will typically chose a faster sequential scan instead. (I suspect that's your case.)
And if there are only few "email" rows, a [**partial index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) instead is much more efficient as it excludes most rows to begin with:

```
CREATE INDEX the_table_email_idx ON the_table ((true))
WHERE value ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9.$%&*+/=?^_{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$';
```

`(true)` is just an arbitrary constant, since there is no obvious index column. Typically, you have a useful index column on top of the "email filter" that can replace that constant - to make the index even more useful. Related:

- [Postgres partial index on IS NULL not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229924/postgres-partial-index-on-is-null-not-working/230087#230087)

Of course, the idea with a [generated column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/939860) `is_email` isn't that bad either. You would then create a partial index with the condition on that generated column instead. There are pros and cons to this.